# How to prevent invisible pages in ViewPagers from onMeasure/onLayout/onDraw?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager, inside it there're some pages, but I find that besides the current active page, all the invisible pages will do onMeasure/onLayout, and it will waste lots of time...

is there a way to disable the backgroud pages to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(int);
```

to set the cached pages. The minimun of cached pages is three (setOffscreenPageLimit(1)): center, left and right of viewpager.